# TSQL Join on columns with different values

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join

I have a table with prices of a product that changes daily, lets say

price (productID int, price float, dateprice datetime).

These prices do not exist at weekends, so there are not all days prices on the table.

I would like a result with a productId, day, todayPrice, yesterdayPrice (obviously the first date would not appear on this result, since it has not a previous day). I thought a join like this would give me what I want, but did not work.

```
select p1.productId, p1.dateprice, p1.price, p2.price
from price p1
inner join price pr ON pr.productId = p1.productId
inner join price p2 ON p1.dateprice = (select max (p.dateprice)
                                       from price p
                                       where p.dateprice < p1.dateprice)
```

This select return an empty result, but if I use "=" instead of "<" it returns me an table with many equal lines (as expected).

How do you suggest me to select this information?

Comment: You didn't reference `p2` in your `ON` clause.

Comment: After the edit... I'm not sure what `pr` does.  Why join from `p1` to `pr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.. but if you're joining one product's price to the previous price, you'll want to make sure that you're including the product Id, otherwise you'd just be joining to any other product's price.

Also, if `p2` is the previous day's price... this is the date that you would check to find the `max (p.dateprice)` that is less than `p1.dateprice`.

```
select 
    p1.productId, p1.dateprice, 
    p1.price as todayPrice, p2.price as yesterdayPrice
from price p1
inner join price p2 
    on p1.productId = p2.productId
    and p2.dateprice = (
        select max (p.dateprice)
        from price p
        where 
            p.dateprice < p1.dateprice
            and p.productId = p1.productId
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, bro, but I forgot to post the first ON condition, the productId. It was on my original query, but althought this, the query still does not work. I just edited the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right track, just change your join condition, like this:

```
select p1.productId, p1.dateprice, p1.price, p2.price
from price p1
inner join price p2 ON p1.productId = p2.productId AND p1.dateprice = DATEADD(day, -1, p2.dateprice) AND p2.dateprice = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE())
```

The `CONVERT` on `GETDATE()` is used to truncate the datetime, assuming your dateprice already has truncated datetimes, that is, with time at 12:00AM. If not, you'll need to use CONVERT to do so. If you want to use MAX() instead to get the latest one, you are better off using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select p1.productId, p1.dateprice, p1.price, p2.price
    from price p1
    CROSS APPLY (select TOP 1 p.price
FROM price p WHERE p.productId = p1.productId ORDER BY p.dateprice DESC) p2
```